# Retina issue (OS X)

Tags: macos, cocoa, retina-display

I am creating a Cocoa app, and when I import @2x images into my project, no image shows up in the app at all. I am using a non-Retina MacBook Pro.

If I have an image, such as image.png, it shows up correctly.

When I import image@2x.png into the project, no image shows when the app is run (even the normal image).

When I change image@2x.png to image@2xx.png (or some other name), the image shows up again. However, now I can't show the image on a Retina device.

Am I not handling Retina images correctly?

Comment: image defect? wrong size?

Comment: You need to have BOTH image.png and image@2x.png in the app bundle. It's not clear from your wording whether you have both or are adding one and removing another.

Comment: @benzado I have both in the bundle. When I don't have the 2x image in the bundle, the image shows correctly. When I add the 2x image to the bundle, nothing shows.

Comment: What happens if you run in the simulator?

Comment: @DavidElliman This is a Mac app. I'm just running it on my computer.

Comment: OK. Don't put the .png extension on when you load the image.

Comment: @DavidElliman That worked - thanks. If you update your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the image.png AND the image@2x.png in your project. Also make sure that when you load the files you do not include the .png extension.